# WP_Query multisite in function.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to retrieve all post type of every multisite to populate a select from ACF PRO. But when I var_dump receive nothing but. It seems I dont even pass on the while have post. But I know "wphr_hr_recruitment" have like 5 instances, and also this code works on page template.

```
function getSites(){
        $args = array(
            'network_id' => null,
            'public'     => null,
            'archived'   => null,
            'mature'     => null,
            'spam'       => null,
            'deleted'    => null,
            'limit'      => 100,
            'offset'     => 0,
        ); 
        $sites = wp_get_sites( $args );
        wp_reset_postdata();
        return $sites;
    }
    function acf_load_job( $field ) {
        $jobs=array();
        $currentJobs=array();
        $sites = getSites();
        foreach ( $sites as $site) {
            switch_to_blog(intval($site['blog_id']));
            $query = new WP_Query( [
                'post_type'      => 'wphr_hr_recruitment',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'order'          => 'DESC',
                'orderby'        => 'post_date'
            ]);
            
            if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
                while ( have_posts()){
                    // $query->next_post();
                    $currentJobs[] = $query->post;
                }                        
            endif;
            wp_reset_postdata();
            restore_current_blog();
        }
        foreach($currentJobs as $currentJob){
            $jobs[$currentJob["ID"]] = $currentJob["post_title"];
        }
        $field['required'] = true;
        $field['choices'] = $jobs;
        return $field;
    }``

The function GetSites retreive all ID so this part seems to work
```

Answer (score 1):

I found something like this, and it's actually work;

```
function getSites(){
        $args = array(
            'network_id' => null,
            'public'     => null,
            'archived'   => null,
            'mature'     => null,
            'spam'       => null,
            'deleted'    => null,
            'limit'      => 100,
            'offset'     => 0,
        ); 
        $sites = wp_get_sites( $args );
        wp_reset_postdata();
        return $sites;
    }
    function acf_load_job( $field ) {
        $jobs=array();
        $sites = getSites();
       
        foreach ( $sites as $site ) {
            switch_to_blog(intval($site['blog_id']));   
            $query = new WP_Query(
                array(
                    'post_type'      => 'wphr_hr_recruitment',
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'order'          => 'DESC',
                    'orderby'        => 'post_date'
                )
            );
            
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
                $query->next_post();
                $expire_date = get_post_meta( $query->post->ID, '_expire_date', true ) ? get_post_meta(  $query->post->ID, '_expire_date', true ) : 'N/A';
                $today = new DateTime('NOW');

                if($expire_date !='N/A'){
                    $e_date = new DateTime($expire_date);
                    if ( $e_date >= $today ) {
                        $jobs[$query->post->ID] = $query->post->post_title;
                    }
                }
                
            }
            restore_current_blog();
        }
      
        $field['required'] = true;
        $field['choices'] = $jobs;
        return $field;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Network_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_network_query/query/)

```
$args =  [
       'post_type'      => 'wphr_hr_recruitment',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'order'          => 'DESC',
       'orderby'        => 'post_date'
   ];
  $query_wphr_hr_recruitment = new Network_Query( $args );
  if( $query_wphr_hr_recruitment->have_posts() ) :
     while( $query_wphr_hr_recruitment->have_posts() ) : $query_wphr_hr_recruitment->the_post();
                 switch_to_blog( $query_wphr_hr_recruitment->post->BLOG_ID );
                 echo '<h2>' . get_the_title( $query_wphr_hr_recruitment->post->ID ) . '</h2>';
                 echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $query_wphr_hr_recruitment->post->ID, 'medium' );
                 echo '<time>' . get_the_time( 'j F, Y', $query_wphr_hr_recruitment->post->ID ) . '</time>';
                 echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $query_wphr_hr_recruitment->post->ID ) . '">Read more</a>';
                 restore_current_blog();
     endwhile;
  else :
     echo '<p>Nothing found for your search criteria.</p>';
  endif;
```

Comment: Thank's for your reply I Just test, but it gives me error : There has been a critical error on this website.

Comment: Indeed, I merged my source code with yours without being able to test. But see another example with Network_Query

Comment: The issue is no matter what I put, Network_Query make my site down. I dont event know why.